# movie clip class parameters ane null

Tags: actionscript-3, class, parameters

I have a movie clip with an external class attached.
here is the MC code (I've shorten it only for the relevant part...)

```
package  {

    //all the imports here...


    public class mc_masterChapter extends MovieClip {

        public function mc_masterChapter() {
            trace (picFile,strChapTitle);
        }



        //Properties 
        public var picFile:String; 
        public var strChapTitle:String;

    }
}
```

In the main class file I'm adding this object to stage using addChild:

```
var masterChapter:mc_masterChapter = new mc_masterChapter;

masterChapter.picFile = "pic_Chap1.jpg";
masterChapter.strChapTitle = "ABCD:

addChildAt(masterChapter,1);
```

now, the trace in the MC class code gives nulls to both parametes but if i put a trace inside the MC timeline (instead of the attached class code), it gives the right value!

how can I access the values from the MC class itself without getting nuls?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It works! Let me explain:

```
var masterChapter:mc_masterChapter = new mc_masterChapter; // Calls class constuctor
                                                           // so calls trace() too!
                                                           // You will get null null

masterChapter.picFile = "pic_Chap1.jpg"; // Assign the variables
masterChapter.strChapTitle = "ABCD";     // so they can be read

trace(masterChapter.picFile, masterChapter.strChapTitle); // Should trace pic_Chap1.jpg ABCD
```

If you add the following method to your class:

```
public function test():void {
    trace(picFile, strChapTitle);
}
```

Then call `masterChapter.test()` it will successfully trace those two properties. So yes, the class can read its properties.

Comment: tnx but you are calling it from the main class (where they were defined) and not from whithin the MC class itself. if you'll look at the code on the top - the trace there gives nulls

Comment: it's intresting. if I'm calling it from the main class (as you suggested) it working. but if I call the same function from whithin the MC class (by writing test(); ) it give back nulls. any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Make the var you use in your main class `public static var`s.

Comment: but I want to use them as the MC parameters (which will change on every placement of the MC on stage) and not as global variables... isnt there a way that I can call these parametes whithin the MC class? (as I said - inside the timeline code it does recognize the data)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a better solution would be to use a getter/setter pair, so you can know at the exact moment the properties are set:

```
protected var _picFile:String:

public function get picFile():String {
   return _picFile;
}

public function set picFile(value:String):void {
   if (value != _picFile) {
     _picFile=value;
     trace('picFile set to', _picFile);
   }
}
```

Comment: but i have alot of parametes.. isn't this a very complicated way of doing what should be simple...?  I'm sure there is a way to access this data from whithin the MC (as I sais, in the timeline code - it does give the right values... only in the package class it gives nulls) I'm pretty sure there is a simple solution to that... Tnx anyway

Comment: Flash Builder will generate most of this code for you automatically if you click your public var and press Ctrl-1 and select "generate getter and setter". If you check "make bindable" and "dispatch custom event", it will even add the value checking code as above (but it will add some extra event dispatching code that's usually not needed in Flash.)

If you really want it to be that simple, you need to be using Flex with its databinding, because the only way to avoid seeing null is to wait until after the values are set. And the only way to know the values are set is to add code (like above).

Comment: i did as you said and got: Error: Error #1023: Stack overflow occurred.
 at mc_masterChapter/get picFile()
 at mc_masterChapter/get picFile()
 at mc_masterChapter/get picFile()
 at mc_masterChapter/get picFile()

Answer (score 0):

OK!

I solved the mystery.

I put two traces. one in the main MC class saying **"hey, I'm inside the MC - the picFile="**
and one in the put Function saying **"I'm putting this file into picFile:"**

well this is what I've got:

> hey, I'm inside the MC - the picFile=null
>
> I'm putting this file into picFile:image.jpg

got it!?! at the moment I asked him to give birth to an instance of the MC (even before putting it on stage - just defining the object (with this line:)

```
var masterChapter:mc_masterChapter = new mc_masterChapter;
```

it allready run the class, so of course that in this stage the parameters were not defined allready and were **null**.

the definition code came right after that line (in the main.as)

```
masterChapter.pic="pic_Chap1.jpg";
```

so what I did, was to move all the code from the main class of the MC object to a public function inside the same package called init(). Then I called this function manually from the parent main class.
By that **I** can decide when to call it (after I declare all the parameters of course).

That's it.

god is hiding in the small details : )
tnx for all the helpers.